# Conexão com WebService SOAP WSDL com retorno XML

Tags: php, web-service, soapclient

Tenho o seguinte código que funciona perfeitamente. O retorno do webservice é um `XML`, mas o retorno que estou recebendo é uma string. O que devo fazer para receber o `XML` como retorno e não uma string?

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.roveri.inf.br/ws/cnpj.php?wsdl');

$function = 'getCNPJ';

$arguments= array(
    'token' => $token,
    'cnpj'  => $cnpj
);

$options = array('location' => 'http://www.roveri.inf.br/ws/cnpj.php');


$result = $client->__soapCall($function, $arguments, $options);

echo 'Response: ';

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode usar **simplexml_load_string** para converter sua string xml para um objeto SimpleXMLElement.

Exemplo:

```
<?php
$xmlstring=
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<teste>
    <pessoa>
        <nome>Alan</nome>
        <profissao>Desenvolvedor Web</profissao>
    </pessoa>
    <pessoa>
        <nome>Alexandre</nome>
        <profissao>Analista de Sistemas</profissao>
    </pessoa>   
</teste>";

$xml=simplexml_load_string($xmlstring) or die("Erro");

var_dump($xml);

foreach($xml as $pessoa)
{
    echo $pessoa->nome."<br>";
}


?>
```